# Having problem with face snapping

Tags: faces, snapping

I am doing the blender Guru latest Donut tutorial and I am currently on the 4th tutorial where we have to do the face snapping. I'm trying to do so but it seems to me that it is wrong though it looks quite snapped still there's a confusion for me. Could you guys look to it and say if it's right or wrong?
[image]

[image]
[image]

Looking at this, it seems snapping worked great But...

[image]
In the last picture, You can see, though it being snapped, the Icing mesh's faces are going inside the donut faces which seems to wrong to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know if you are aware that face snapping means usually one vertex which you move gets snapped onto some (eventually the closest) face. That doesn't make all other vertices around snap to their near faces as well.

So although one vertex sits on the face, others may be going inside the surface of the donut. But even if not, you have a *Subdivision Surface* modifier on the icing smoothening the mesh which to some extent may also cause the mesh to be inside even though the unsubdivided mesh would be fully outside.

To change that you would have to move all those vertices that you suppose to be placed wrong. Usually you would enable *Proportional Editing* (shortcut <kbd>O</kbd>) so that you can move one vertex and the surrounding follow along to some degree, which might not be perfect but it helps.

The other thing is, it does not have to be perfect. There's a reason you add thickness to the icing with a *Solidify* modifier. First of all of course because in real liefe icing has no zero thickness, but on the other hand it can cover up slight variations in the placing of the mesh. Apart from that, with an even thickness created by the modifier, some parts of the mesh have to go inside the donut to vary the appearance of the thickness a bit over the whole surface.

And the last thing is: will you see the inside of the donut in the end? Does it matter if some vertices are on the inside? Does Andrew show the inside of the donut and do all vertices stay perfectly on the outside in his model?